# logparser Message with error codes

Tags: logparser, windows-event-log

Is there anyway to get complete error message using LogParser?

When I run the following query:

```
logparser -i:EVT -o:NAT "SELECT TimeGenerated,EventID,Message from System WHERE EventTypeName='Error event'"
```

I get the following output:

```
2009-09-02 19:35:44 7000    The USB Mass Storage Driver service failed to start due to the following error: %%1058
```

The full "Message" in EventViewer is:

> Description: 
>   The USB Mass Storage
>   Driver service failed to start due to
>   the following error:
>   The service
>   cannot be started, either because it
>   is disabled or because it has no
>   enabled devices associated with it.

How can I obtain complete message using logparser?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Windows are you running?  I've experienced the same errors more frequently on Server 2008 than on Server 2003.  I believe it's related to registering DLLs.